# how to return an arrays of the free days using DateTime

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using **Laravel 9** to create lessons scheduler,

I tried that way but Im little lost,

```
$free_time_frame = [[]];  // nested array here

$start = new DateTime("2023-01-01");
$end = new DateTime("2023-12-31");

$interval = new DateInterval("P1D"); // 1 month interval
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
$seasons = ["2023-02-01", "2023-02-13"];
foreach ($period as $date) {
  if (in_array($date->format("Y-m-d"), $seasons)) {
    // Skip the rest of the loop if the current month is in the $seasons array
    $free_time_frame[] = [];   // append nested array
    continue;
  }

  // Set the start date to the first day of the month
  $start_date = new DateTime($date->format("Y-m-01"));
  // Set the end date to the last day of the month
  $end_date = new DateTime($date->format("Y-m-t"));

  // Calculate the number of days between the start and end dates
  $diff = $start_date->diff($end_date);
  $days = $diff->days + 1; // Add 1 to include the end date

  // use the latest nested array
  

}
```

I'm booking `$seasons` I would like to have an array of the free days before `"2023-02-01"` and days after `"2023-02-13"` like that :

Expected Result

```
[
  [
   "2023-01-01",
   "2023-01-02",
   "2023-01-03",
   "..."
   "2023-01-31",
  ]
  [
   "2023-02-14",
   "2023-02-15",
   "2023-02-16",
   "2023-02-14",
   "and so on util the end of the year"
  ]
]
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: How do we know *free days*?

Comment: and your **Start** and **End** date are `2022`. Welcome to `2023` if you need to query on new year `$start = new DateTime("2022-01-01");
$end = new DateTime("2022-12-31");`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam. question updated ( start & end dates fixed ) 
free days = are the days not in range of $seasons

check the expected result

Comment: Assume `$seasons` has only two dates, and you want to return all 363(365-2) dates?

Comment: there should be no free days between the two seasons I have, like the expected result

Comment: so you have 1 season... and its around 14 days, and you want to split them by weeks?

Comment: @KGG I just don't want to have some thing between the dates I have In $seasons

Comment: @rudiger what you are saying, what your code is doing, and what you posted as expected results.. none of it matches.. can you try to reword your question, or explain in simple terms 1) what you have, 2) what you want as a final result.

Comment: @KGG please check my expected result

Comment: This may not be the answer you're looking for but Carbon allows you to create date periods and then you can exclude dates from those periods 

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period

Answer (score 1):

To calculate free time from `$seasons` that doesn't include in-between time period, it is just the everything before your first element of your seasons array and everything after last element of your seasons array.

So, achieving this is just running 2 loops of DatePeriod in those ranges.

```
<?php

$seasons = ["2023-02-01", "2023-02-13", "2023-03-16"];

$free_time_frame = [];

$free_time_frame[] = getDaysInPeriod('2023-01-01', 'P1D', current($seasons));
$free_time_frame[] = getDaysInPeriod(date("Y-m-d", strtotime(end($seasons). " +1 days")), 'P1D', '2024-01-01');


function getDaysInPeriod($startDate, $dateInterval, $endDate){
  $span = [];
  foreach(new DatePeriod(new DateTime($startDate), new DateInterval($dateInterval),new DateTime($endDate)) as $p){
    $span[] = $p->format('Y-m-d');
  }
  return $span;
}

$free_time_frame = array_filter($free_time_frame);

print_r($free_time_frame);
```

[**Online Fiddle**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3ytvcm6mn)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do the following:

```
$startDate = '2023-01-01';
$endDate = '2023-03-31';

$seasons = ['2023-02-01', '2023-02-13'];

$prepareSeasons = [
    [ $startDate, Carbon::parse($seasons[0])->subDay()->format('Y-m-d') ],
    [ Carbon::parse($seasons[0])->addDay()->format('Y-m-d'), $endDate ]
];

// this is want we want to achieve
// $prepareSeasons = [
//     [$startDate, '2023-01-31'],
//     ['2023-02-14', $endDate],
// ];

$freeTimeFrame = [];

foreach ($prepareSeasons as $seasonDates)
{
    $freeSeason = [];

    $seasonDates = CarbonPeriod::create($seasonDates[0], $seasonDates[1])->toArray();

    foreach ($seasonDates as $date)
    {
        array_push($freeSeason, $date->format('Y-m-d'));
    }

    array_push($freeTimeFrame, $freeSeason);
}

return $freeTimeFrame;
```

The code above will achieve your expected result

```
[
  [
   "2023-01-01",
   "2023-01-02",
   "2023-01-03",
   "...",
   "...",
   "2023-01-31",
  ],
  [
   "2023-02-14",
   "2023-02-15",
   "2023-02-16",
   "2023-02-14",
   "...",
   "...",
   "2023-12-31",
  ]
]
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think I understand, that you want to get all dates between a range of dates, then exclude a specific range of date.

**You can do it like this:**

```
$originalDates = \Carbon\CarbonPeriod::between('2023-01-01', '2023-01-10')->toArray();
$excludedDates = \Carbon\CarbonPeriod::between('2023-01-03', '2023-01-06')->toArray();
        
$finalDates = [];
        
foreach ($originalDates as $date) {
    if(!in_array($date, $excludedDates)){
        array_push($finalDates, $date->format('d-m-Y'));
    }
}
    
return $finalDates;
```

**This will return an array of the following results:**

```
01-01-2023
02-01-2023
07-01-2023
08-01-2023
09-01-2023
10-01-2023
```

Notice here that it skipped over from `2023-01-03` to `2023-01-06`

You can format this as you like by changing the line of `$date->format('d-m-Y')` to represent the results the way you want it, you can even remove the format to return a carbon array, which you can parse as you like somewhere else.

And you can go one step further, and have multiple `excludedDates`, and check for them `in_array`

Hopefully this helps, add a comment if you want further clarifications or modifications.